# In Windows, what is a built-in way to make drag-and-drop more difficult to occur accidentally?

Tags: windows, file-permissions, drag-and-drop

Is there a "native" Windows way to prevent users from accidentally moving folders and files due to accidental "drag-and-drop"?

Because of the default of a 4-pixel movement needed to trigger a drag-and-drop event during a mouse button being pressed, a slight jerk while clicking on a folder or file icon can easily cause an unintended drag-and-drop event.  I want to help my clients avoid this problem *by making drag-and-drop more difficult to occur accidentally*, but I want it to be simple to explain over the phone and not require installing software nor doing registry tweaks.

Here's what I've found so far. These may work to solve the problem, except that they involve installing third-party software or doing registry hacks:

1. Adding an “are you sure you want to move/copy this” confirmation box [by installing *dragdropinterceptopr*](http://broken-e.com/dragdropinterceptor).
2. Adjusting the distance you have to drag something before it is “dragged and dropped”:

   - [By installing *Dragsens* and using it to adjust this setting](http://www.parkscomputing.com/2013/12/windows-version-of-dragsens/)
   - [By editing the registry directly (as shown in this link).](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/disable-drag-and-drop-in-windows) (**WARNING**: Do a system backup or create a restore point before this. Only do this if you are really truly familiar with the registry and have done something like this before. Mistakes in the registry can cause your system to quit working in bizarre ways.)

Comment: @LPChip Thanks. I hadn't realized how little background I provided.

Comment: Much better. :)

Answer (score -3):

1. Use a good mouse. I found the very basic ones work great.
2. Always use copy-paste or cut-paste to copy/move.
3. When there was an accidental move, CTRL-Z should undo the move.
4. Don't try to drag and drop when system is busy.

Comment: This is not answering the question. Its a bit like when I ask: my car is heavy on fuel usage. How can I drive to make sure the fuel consumtion is as low as possible, and you answer: easy, don't drive your car.

Comment: @Codism. Sorry, my question wasn't very clear. I've improved it some.